# Passing URI Segments to your methods

Tags: codeigniter-3

Im going through codeigniter-3 tutorial and I dont fully understand what they mean with this:

"If you are using the URI Routing feature, the segments passed to your method will be the re-routed ones."

Its under "Passing URI Segments to your methods"

code displayed:

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

        public function shoes($sandals, $id)
        {
                echo $sandals;
                echo $id;
        }
}
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Are the segments the arguments passed in to the function and what do they mean with they will be re-routed?
I checked the URI Routing feature but still dont understand.
Can anyone can explain what they mean?

Comment: well mate why do you get when you `echo $sandals; echo $id;`? in other words, what do you get by running shoes?

Comment: index.php/Product/shoes/green/10 would display green 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in your case, I would suggest you to read on [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html), to get more information regarding what's going on.

But as to answer your questions, if you are for example defining new URI's to change your URL as you like, then by calling `shoes($sandals, $id)`, you will get the parameters that were manipulated in the re-routing process, and not the original ones.

In other words, **if** you have tried re-routing your URI's

**from** *index.php/Product/shoes/blue/10* **to** *index.php/Product/shoes/green/10*

then by calling `shoes($sandals, $id)` you will get **green** and **10**, as you mentioned, note the blue will not be displayed then.

Comment: something like this right, $route['product/shoes/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/shoes/green/$2';

Comment: Ah so are you saying you **have** used re-routing?